# Evaluation of the following Series

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Hi there,

I was wondering if you guys could be able to find the sum of the following series:

$ S = 1/((1\cdot2)^2) + 1/((3\cdot4)^2) + 1/((5\cdot6)^2) + ... + 1/(((2n-1)\cdot2n)^2) $, in which $\{n\to\infty}$ .

This question came to mind when I was looking at this (http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~dasgupta/publications/tr02-03.pdf) paper by Professor Anirban DasGupta. In the last section, a couple of specific examples of his 'unified' method to find the sums of infinite series is pressented. In equation (34), he states that the following series:

$ 1/(1\cdot2) + 1/(3\cdot4) + 1/(5\cdot6) + ... 1/(2n\cdot(2n-1)) = log(2)  $ (Note that $\{n\to\infty}$ again). I was wondering If it's possible to find the sum if the values of the denominators of the terms are squared.

Thanks in advance,

Max Muller

Comment: The second sum which you have written does not sum to $\log 2$.  It is an alternating series which sums to 1.

Comment: Maple gives the value $-3+\pi^2/3$.  More generally, let $f(r) = 1/2^r + 1/12^r + 1/30^r + \cdots$, so your sum is $f(2)$.  Then Maple gives $f(3) = 10-\pi^2, f(4) = -35+10\pi^2/3+\pi^4/45$, and in general $f(r)$ is a linear combination with rational coefficients of even powers of $\pi$. There appears to be some general theory at work here but I don't know what it is, which is why this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Michael, your "general theory" is simply that 1/(x(x+1))^n is a sum of a bunch of x^j and (x+1)^j, for j varying over even integers between -n and -1.  Just subtract off the principal parts of the Laurent series around 0 and -1; that gives an entire function which decays at infinity, hence equals zero.

Comment: I'm confused now... Below, both Peter Luthy and David Hansen think the infinite sum converges to $pi^2/3 -3$ Micheal Greenblatt, however, believes that $pi^2/6-2log2$ equals S. Who's right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Okay, so perhaps "general theory" made it sound fancier than it is.

Comment: David Hansen, could you perhaps elaborate on your method, using the partial fractions and $zeta(2)$ ? Or do you know a paper which proves this result?

Comment: That being said, my original comment is in error; I was summing every term, and we only want every other term.

Comment: Ah, I see, you have written the general term down incorrectly, Max. It is not $1/(n(n+1))^2$ . It should be $1/(2n(2n-1))^2$.

Comment: Oh yes, I think you're right, Peter Luthy, thank you for correcting me. I will correct the question.

Comment: OK, I looked at the first three terms and saw you were wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it equals $\frac{\pi^2}{3}-3$. This follows from applying partial fractions and using $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Comment: haha I had just written this up a second before the site indicated you posted your solution... here is what I wrote:
Write $\frac{1}{n^2(n+1)^2}=\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^2=\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{2}{n(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$.  Summing the first term gives $\pi^2/6$, the last term gives $-1+\pi^2/6$, and the middle term is an alternating seriesgives $-2$, so that the whole sum is $\frac{\pi^2}{3}-3$.

Comment: Presumably this generalizes to give the $f(r)$ I alluded to.

Comment: I think he's adding up over every other $n$ so it's ${\pi^2 \over 6} - 2 \log 2$.

Comment: Peter Luthy, according to the paper (to which the link directs you) the second sum I provided you all with actually does converge to log(2). If you don't agree with the author of the paper, please contact him, Anirban DasGupta. I thank you for your other contributions, though

Comment: Peter is in error, log 2 is correct.

Comment: Gerald, Max wrote the incorrect general term, hence my error.

$\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{((2n-1)2n)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{((2n-1)2n)^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n)^2}}$.

The first and second sums add to give $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}}$, which then gives Michael Greenblatt's result.

Comment: So, would Micheal Greenblatt's result equal S? If so, please give your (correct?) answer and motivate it. If you know where to find a concise proof, or if you could give us one, to prove your statement, please do. I don't know who's 'right' now, David Hansen or Micheal Greenblatt. Perhaps David Hansen gave the correct answer to a question I didn't pose in the right manner, at first. Could someone please clarify?