# Evaluation of the following series... $S = 1/(2\times3) + 1/(5\times6) + 1/(7\times8) + 1/(10\times11) + ...  $

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

EDIT, Will Jagy, December 8, 2010: to anyone considering working on this, please first see  http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/817/could-a-few-moderators-please-remove-one-of-my-questions/#Item_9 
which gives the story behind this peculiar sum. Note that the OP is no longer interested in the results, as they arose from one kind of error and cannot be applied because of a different sort of misunderstanding. The double sum version below was provided recently by Harald Hanche-Olsen.

ORIGINAL. I'm curious one of you is able to find the exact evaluation of 
the following series:

$$\begin{aligned} S &= 1/(2\times3) +1/(5\times6) + 1/(7\times8) + 1/(10\times11) + \cdots 
  \\\\&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{(n^2+2k-1)(n^2+2k)} \end{aligned}$$

I'm not exactly sure on how to state the 'general term' of the series. Perhaps I can illustrate it with an example:

$ 1/(1\times2) + 1/(3\times4) + 1/(5\times6) + 1/(7\times8) + \ldots + 1/((2n - 1) \times 2n) + \ldots = \log(2)$.

Now, to answer Nate Eldredge: let $a_0=2$ and $a_{k+1}=a_{k} + 1 $ unless $ a_{k} + 1$ is a square, in which case let $a_{k + 1} = a_{k} + 2$. Now, multiply $a_{k}$ with $a_{k+1}$. That's a term. Let me show the first few terms:

$ S = 1/(2\times3)$ [now skip 4] $ +  1/(5\times6) + 1/(7\times8)$ [now skip 9] $ + 1/(10\times11) + 1/(12\times13) + 1/(14\times15)$ [now skip 16] $ + 1/(17\times18) + \ldots $

So all the squares (1,4,9,16,25, etc) are 'skipped' in the terms.

I hope this clarifies it a bit...

Thanks a lot in advance,

Max Muller

*PS: If someone has any ideas as to how the general term of this series can be written in a more concise manner, please let me know! For the Meta-users, see also the relevant [discussion](http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/817/could-a-few-moderators-please-remove-one-of-my-questions/#Item_9) on this question.*

Comment: Is there a mistake in your series? It's not quite clear how the general term relates to your first few terms.

Comment: So to clarify, let $a_0 = 2$, $a_{k+1} = a_k + 1$ if $a_k + 1$ is not a perfect square, $a_{k+1} = a_k + 2$ otherwise.  You are asking about $S = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 1/(a_{2k} a_{2k+1})$.  Have I got it right?

Comment: Classical, I think.

Comment: If you intend the sum as in Nate's comment above, then this is a standard calculus problem.  The magic phrase is "telescoping series."

Comment: But he apparently wants to omit those terms of the form $1/(n^2(n^2+1))$ and $1/(n^2-1)n^2$.

Comment: Dealing with those omitted terms is not standard calculus, although there are standard techniques to do it.

Comment: Oh!  Now I understand the question.  Sorry.

Comment: You should write the series in the title of the question as well.

Comment: Ok, I will do that immediately. I didn't know you're supposed to do so.

Comment: \times is the LaTeX code for the multiplication cross; $1 \times 2$ looks much nicer than $1x2$.  If you want a multiplication dot, it's \cdot.

Comment: Thanks JBL, I'll change it . I thought it looked a bit strange as well..

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand the question. Is it to give a closed form evaluation of: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{(k^2+2i-1)(k^2+2i)}$? The internal sum has a closed form in terms of the digamma function $\psi$ (logarithmic derivative of $\Gamma$).

Comment: Mathematica reports the sum as being close to 0.2666107465545, which doesn't seem to be in the inverse calculator. No time for a smart lookup...

Comment: Here are 100 digits of accuracy, a number which makes no appearance in the inverse symbolic calculator: 0.2666107465 5453168613 6628089774 8241503666 2708930887 0641966251 9954601539 3188197508 1358607768 1376413658


Comment: Is WZ theory in order?

Comment: @ Elohemamahab: What does WZ stand for? @ Kevin: thanks for looking the approximate value up. Yes, the question is indeed to give closed form evaluations of the double sum you gave.

Comment: WZ stands for the Wilf-Zeilberger method. See, e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf–Zeilberger_pair

Answer (score 15):

I thought I'd add in my favorite way of computing sums of the form 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{p(n)}{q(n)}$$
for $p$ and $q$ polynomials.

First, expand in partial fractions:
$$\frac{p(n)}{q(n)} = \sum \frac{a_i}{n+s_i} + \mbox{terms for repeated roots}.$$

Since the sum is to converge, we must have $p(n)/q(n) =O(n^{-2})$, so $\sum a_i=0$. So rewrite this as 
$$\frac{p(n)}{q(n)} = \sum a_i \left( \frac{1}{n+s_i} - \frac{1}{n} \right) + \mbox{terms for repeated roots}.$$

We are now reduced to evaluating sums of the form
$$\sum \left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+s} \right)$$
and
$$\sum \frac{1}{(n+s)^k}$$

We have the identity
$$\sum \left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+s}\right) = \frac{\Gamma'(s)}{\Gamma(s)} + \gamma + \frac{1}{s}$$
where $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function and $\gamma$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant. See, for example, [this website](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/improper/gamma/gamma.html). Taking repeated derivatives of this gives a formula for $\sum 1/(n+s)^k$.

So, if you accept derivatives of the $\Gamma$ function at algebraic numbers, such sums can always be evaluated. In general, I don't know a better method. However, in many cases, one can use familiar $\Gamma$ function identities to do better. Here are three tricks, all of which come up in our setting:

1. If we ever have to deal with $\sum \left( \frac{1}{n+s} - \frac{1}{n+k+s} \right)$, then the sum telescopes. We can see this on the $\Gamma$ function side: $\Gamma(s+k) = (s+k-1)\cdots (s+1) (s) \Gamma(s)$ and taking logarithimic derivatives gives a relation between $\Gamma(s+k)/\Gamma'(s+k)$ and $\Gamma'(s)/\Gamma(s)$.
2. If we ever have to deal with $\sum \left( \frac{1}{n-s} - \frac{1}{n+s} \right)$, recall that
   $$\Gamma(s) \Gamma(-s) = \frac{\pi}{s \sin (\pi s)}.$$
   Taking logarithimic derivatives of this will give you a formula for $\Gamma'(s)/\Gamma(s) - \Gamma'(-s)/\Gamma(-s)$. Repeated derivatives will deal with $\sum \left( \frac{1}{(n-s)^k} - \frac{1}{(n+s)^k} \right)$. It is important to note that all of these formulas work for $s$ complex; for example, in the current example we need to deal with $s=i/2$.
3. Remember that $\zeta(2k)$ is already known, and is easy to look up that than the Taylor series of $\Gamma$ around $0$.

Comment: @ David: although it doesn't adress the question, I very much appreciate the fact that you have given me this information. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**NB:** *It seems that after this answer was written, the asker "made precise" what he wanted, and I think this has been rendered more or less irrelevant...*

**NB2:** *Maybe the people voting down this can explain their votes?*

Assuming you want to sum the terms of $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1{n(n+1)}$ which are not of the form $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n^2(n^2+1)}$ or $\displaystyle\frac{1}{(n^2-1)n^2}$, you can do it by computing the first sum (by the telescoping trick) and then substracting the sum of the terms you want to exclude. To compute the sums you need to substract, say, $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{1}{(n^2-1)n^2}$, you can compute it as the sum of residues of $\frac{\cot z}{z^4-z^2}$ at $2$, $3$, $4$, etc, using a bit of complex analysis (as in the 8th solution of the Basel problem presented by R. Chapman [here](http://secamlocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/etc/zeta2.pdf))

Comment: But the point seems to be to "restart" after each square, adding number of terms and stopping? So that the general term is misleading as given. 

Comment: No, I don't think I want to omit the terms of the form $1/(n^2(n^2+1))$ or 1/(n^2(n^2-1)) . I don't think this is some classical problem of a calculus textbook. Let me edit my question a bit, perhaps I can clarify it.

Comment: We have $1/(n^2(n^2-1))=-1/n^2 + 1/2(n-1) - 1/2(n+1)$, so this sum is $latex -\zeta(2)$ plus a telescoping term. I think that the other omitted term genuinely requires the residue trick, though.

Comment: Indeed, Mathematica sums that one to $\frac{7}{4}-\frac{\pi ^2}{6}$, which screams zeta, while the other one to $\frac{1}{6} \pi  (\pi -3 \coth (\pi ))$, which screams residues :)

Comment: Please reformulate with a -1 to the power of floor function of square root of n, applied to alternating reciprocals, and omitting the squares. Then I think we might understand. "Classical" does not mean calculus textbook, necessarily, though.

Comment: @Charles, I do not understand neither of your two comments!

Comment: @ mister Alvarez: please look at my question in its restated form. I think the question now requires for a different answer. Sorry for the phrasing in of the question in its previous form, it was far from clear... 

Comment: I’m now considering 

Ʃ a(k)/k 

where a(k) = 0 when k is a square, and otherwise a(k) = -1<sup>b(k)</sup> with b(k) = k + [square root(k)], [ ] being integral part. This is meant to be equivalent to the OP's intended series, up to some factor of plus or minus 2 or something.

Comment: It's just irritating to conceal the partial fraction decomposition, though.

Comment: @jc I don't think I want something like 1/((2n-1)*2n) for terms "greater than an odd number of squares". I'd like to take the sum of reciprocials of: 2*3, [4] 5*6, 7*8, [9] 10*11, 12*13, 14*15, [16] 17*18, 19*20, 21*22, 23*24, [25] 26*27 etc. Notice that all the [squares] are left out! The squares 'don't belong' to the sum. They aren't multiplied with the other, non-square numbers or added to the sequence whatsoever. 

Comment: OK, in this forum, please don't use "compsci" notation for multiplication, and please do use sigma notation. We can all write 1/6 = 1/2 - 1/3 here, so could you verify that my a(k) is what you want?

Comment: @Max, you're right, of course.  I understood what you meant but my description came out quite wrong.  I've removed it since there are plenty of correct descriptions in this thread now.

Comment:  @ Charles: I'm not sure what your a(k) is... My computer does not display the LaTeX in your comment on a(k). I don't know what the <sup> means and I don't understand your method very well. I'm sorry for not being able to understand your methods... Please explain it to me. Perhaps I could verify it, then

Comment: @Max, the <sup> is an html tag which is supposed to raise the b(k) into the exponent.  Thus a(k) = (-1)^(b(k)) in "compsci" notation.  I believe Charles's strategy is to use a partial fraction decomposition to get terms proportional to 1/k.

Comment: @ Charles If you think you've interpreted my question correctly, you can answer me anyway. Perhaps it then becomes clear to me how your method works. I think it's annoying I can't send anyone any personal messages on mathoverflow though. I think it can be useful from time to time. (I hint at the moderators of this site! I hope you can discuss this on the meta-page).

Comment: Not that it matters, but you can get the sum of 1/(n^2 + 1) as (pi/ 2) coth pi without using residues, using the Poisson summation formula instead in conjunction with the fact that the Fourier transform of e^{-|t|} is a constant times 1/(x^2 + 1). It's actually exercise 12 Chapter 9 of Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis".

Comment: ok... thank you Michael. You've helped to evaluate one of my series before. Could you please help me with this one? And what do you think of Charles' methods? 

Comment: I agree with Mariano Suarez-Alvarez's overall method. You have a telescoping sum, easily evaluated, minus the sum of (1/n^2(n^2 - 1)) minus the sum of (1/n^2(n^2 +1)). What David Speyer suggested for the sum of (1/n^2(n^2 - 1)) should be relatively painless. For the second sum write (1/n^2(n^2 +1)) = 1/n^2 - 1/(n^2 + 1). The first sums to pi^2/6 and the second gives the pi/2 coth pi. 

Comment: Ok, thanks Michael. I think Mariano Suarez-Alvarez has a nice method indeed, but I'm not sure the terms he's generated are exactly the same as in the question I asked... 
Ok, so you have the values of the two sums you need to subtract from the telescopic sum. Could you pleaese tell me what the telescopic sum amounts to?

Comment: Um mister Alvarez, could you please look at our discussion on Charles' answer?

Comment: That's a nice solution, but definitely not the solution of the proposed problem, that seems to me a bit harder than that. Max Muller clearly stated the series he want to sum; for instance, he definitely do not want the term 1/6*7, that clearly appears in Mariano Suarez-Alvarez series. In fact, I can't see in the original series any telescopic sum either... Am I missing soething? – Pietro Majer 0 secs ago

Comment: Oops, I just assumed he was answering your original question. Sorry about that.

Comment: Mariano, I'm not one who voted (I have rarely voted on anything). I think it is worth looking at Max Muller's earlier question on series and the one reference mentioned.

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24258/

Comment: @ Mariano I voted down because I thought it would be better if another answer would be the first other people would see, because I thought people would be confused to see your answer because they'd think this is the right answer because it has the most votes. I shouldn't have downvoted your answer, though, as you probably gave the correct answer to question in its previous state (in which it was phrased horribly). I upvoted your answer again because I think I can't blame you for my bad phrasing. Besides, you tried to help me anyway by thinking about and answering the question.

Answer (score 6):

As already mentioned by Mariano, the sum in question is a simple logarithmic sum minus
$$
\sum_{n>1}\biggl(\frac1{n^2(n^2-1)}+\frac1{n^2(n^2+1)}\biggr)
=2\sum_{n>1}\frac1{n^4-1}
=\frac74-\frac\pi2\coth\pi.
$$
The closed form evaluation is mentioned in Michel Waldschmidt's
["Open Diophantine Problems"](http://people.math.jussieu.fr/~miw/articles/pdf/ODP-MoscowMathJ.pdf) (Moscow Math. Journal 4:1 (2004), 245-305, 312) together with "which is a transcendental number since $\pi$ and $e^\pi$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb Q$ (Yu.V. Nesterenko)."

**EDIT.** I was confused by too many answers and edits. On using
$$
\frac1{n(n+1)}=\frac1n-\frac1{n+1},
$$
one can write the wanted sum as
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+[\sqrt n]-1}}n+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+[\sqrt n]-1}}n+\frac{\pi^2}6.
$$
I can hardly imagine that the remaining single sum has a closed form... But this leaves a nice problem in 1st year analysis: *Show that the series*
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+[\sqrt n]}}n
$$
*converges.*

Comment: I think the answer has been found, finally! Thanks, Wadim Zudilin.

Comment: Hi Wadim,I don't think you've read the question correctly (but it's hard to tell because I don't know precisely what you mean by "a simple logarithmic sum"). Each non-square positive integer $i$ appears here as a factor in the denominator of exactly one term of the sum.

Comment: (You'll see that this sum was already worked out by Mariano in the 4th comment on Mariano's answer.)

Comment: @ Wadim: I'm afraid JBL is right, I'm sorry I accepted and then 'unaccepted' your answer.

Comment: @Wadim: That *is* a nice problem. +1

Answer (score 4):

**rmk 1.** After some manipulation of the series, if

$f(x):=1 - \frac{1-x}{1+x}\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} x^{k^2}$

Then

$S:=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{f(x)}{x} dx.$

So this confirms Charles Matthews' hint:

$\theta:=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} x^{k^2}$
Is the theta series, indeed, linked to the Jacobi theta function. (But I don't know how to proceed then.)

**rmk 2**. Maybe writing Max Muller's series as a sum over double indices (k,n)

$S:=\sum_{1\le k\le n} \frac{1}{(n^2+2k-1)(n^2+2k)}$

one can find a smart partition of the set of indices that allows an iterate summation. (very few chances of success). For instance changing the order of summation, i.e.

$S:=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{1}{(n^2+2k-1)(n^2+2k)}$

The inner sum can be treated via partial fraction decomposition and summed as illustrated by David Speyer; I found (with $\Psi:=\Gamma'/\Gamma$)

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\ \left( \mathrm{Im}\frac{\Psi(k+i\sqrt{2k-1})}{\sqrt{2k-1}}-\mathrm{Im}\frac{\Psi(k+i\sqrt{2k})}{\sqrt{2k}}\right)=0.2666107..$

Comment: Thanks, Pietro. But isn't a 'double sum' a sum of a sum? So shouldn't there be two sigmas in rmk 2?

Comment: To be precise, it's a single sum over a set of double indices (k,n) :-) , that you can sum in any order and with any partition you like, since all terms are positive. I added a few lines that may be of some interest to make a quicker numeric evaluation.


Comment: @Pietro : I think your integral representation of the sum gives a very fast way to evaluate $S$ numerically, using the functional equation of $\theta$. This seems to give a double sum but this time with an exponentially decreasing factor.

Comment: Interesting! will you please add some detail? 

Answer (score 3):

As you are interested in $ \zeta(3) $ you might prefer this variant of your construction. This is also a small part of what Pietro Majer would have done in the direction indicated by Charles Matthews.

Define $ f(x)$ for $ | x | \leq 1 $ by

$$  
 f(x)   =  \frac{x^4}{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4} + \frac{x^7}{5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7}   +  \frac{x^{11}}{9 \cdot 10 \cdot 11}  +  \frac{x^{14}}{12 \cdot 13 \cdot 14}  +\cdots + \frac{x^{30}}{28 \cdot 29 \cdot 30} +  \frac{x^{33}}{31 \cdot 32 \cdot 33} + \cdots
    $$

Then I took the third derivative, power series has all coefficients 1 and simplifies as

$$ f'''(x) = (x + x^4 ) + ( x^8 + x^{11} + \cdots + x^{23}) + ( x^{27} + x^{30} + \cdots) + \cdots $$

$$ f'''(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \; \; x^{n^3}   \left( \frac{1 - x^{3 n^2 + 3 n}}{1 - x^3}   \right)  $$ 
or

$$ \left( \frac{1 }{1 - x^3}   \right) \cdot \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \; \; x^{n^3} - x^{n^3 + 3 n^2 + 3 n} \right) $$

$$ \left( \frac{1 }{1 - x^3}   \right) \cdot \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \; \; x^{n^3} - \left( \frac{1}{x}   \right)  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \; \; x^{(n + 1)^3} \right) $$

$$ \left( \frac{1 }{1 - x^3}   \right) \cdot \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \; \; x^{n^3} - \left( \frac{1}{x}   \right)  \sum_{m=2}^\infty \; \; x^{m^3} \right) $$

$$ \left( \frac{1 }{1 - x^3}   \right) \cdot \left( 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \; \; x^{n^3} - \left( \frac{1}{x}   \right)  \sum_{m=1}^\infty \; \; x^{m^3} \right) $$

$$ \left( \frac{1 }{1 - x^3}   \right) \cdot \left( 1  - \left( \frac{1-x}{x}   \right)  \sum_{m=1}^\infty \; \; x^{m^3} \right) $$

$$ f'''(x) = \left( \frac{1 }{1 - x^3}   \right) - \left( \frac{1}{x ( 1 + x + x^2)}   \right)  \sum_{m=1}^\infty \; \; x^{m^3}  $$

And so on more or less forever, with no explicit value for $f(1)$ likely.

Answer (score 2):

Anyway, I think the point is that with a(k) a sequence of the type implicated here, namely blocks of +1 and -1 alternating, jumping and flipping over at k any square, the generating function of the a(k) is composed of blocks of geometric series. If the variable is t, each finite geometric series can be summed with denominator 1 + t. At this stage I think Euler could handle the question? Rational function times a theta-series, I believe. This needs to be integrated formally, and the limit as t -> 1 from below taken. This would be the "classical" approach.

I apologise if this is nonsense.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have understood your 'classical approach... Could you describe what you're doing in 'mathematical language?'. And why do you think Euler could handle this question? Has he evaluated this series already? Please ellaborate on your methods, anyway!

Comment: I have to say that I'm not going to type more mathematical notation here, given your reaction above. It is a bit ironic that you ask for an explanation in mathematical language. It is not clear to me whether this is a challenge problem to which you already know the answer, but I'm not highly motivated yet (whether it is or not). You have ignored the request I made to formulate the series in sigma notation: "..." can waste a lot of time, as the discussion shows.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't formulate the series in sigma notation, I'm not very familiar with LaTeX and I more or less forgot to listen to your request. Of course I know your speaking in 'matematical language', I was thinking more of symbols and an exact proof. I was just interested in your approach and I tried to encourage you to expand your answer, as mister Alvarez probably gave a nice and correct answer, but not a very 'clean proof'. I think it's nice to have more than one solution to a problem, but if you don't want to type any more mathematical notation anymore, I understand.

Comment: You realise that Alvarez adds 1/5x6, 1/6x7, 1/7x8, 1/10x11, 1/11x12 etc.?

Comment: No.. I didn't realize that. I thought he added 1/5x6, 1/7x8, 1/10x11 etc., which is what I would've liked. I had some doubts, but Michael Greenblatt convinced me.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect answer deleted.

Comment: But what is left is not Max Muller's series either :-( 
the terms 1/2x3 or 1/10x11 are still lacking, while there are extra terms as 1/13x14 not included in Max's series.


Comment: Grr, you're right. He keeps doing things which seem bizarre. OK, I'll rethink this.

Comment: I guess you're right Will. I'm young and inexperienced but I'm also willing to work and think hard to understand things. But did you say this because David Speyer said 'he keeps doing things which seem bizarre'? Because I'm not sure David was referring to me when he said 'he'.. or are you, David? 

Comment: I was. Of course, I have no ideal what the motivation for this sum is. But the way you are dropping out terms means that you are switching between sums of the form $\sum 1/((2k)(2k+1))$ and $\sum 1/((2k-1)(2k))$. I think I kept misreading the definition because that seemed like a very difficult and unmotivated thing to do; if I were just making up a sum for the fun of it, I wouldn't do that. 

Comment: I hope this doesn't come off as hostile. It wasn't meant to be, and I will be  interested to hear if anyone finds a closed form for your sum

Comment: Well I can tell you a bit about my motivation ;). It's a bit more 'nobel' than just inventing a series just for the fun of it... I think it's related to Apéry's constant. 

Answer (score -2):

S=1/(2×3)+1/(5×6)+1/(7×8)+1/(10×11)+...=**1/20(20-2(pi)Sqrt(5-2Sqrt(5))
-2Sqrt(5)ArcCoth(Sqrt(5))-5Log(5))=0.2617882198...(approx.)**

Comment: The name of a real number with no explanation where it came from is of close to 0 value.

Comment: Can you give a proof?

Comment: The sum in the question has value more than 0.2666 , so this answer is wrong.  I get 0.2666 by adding terms up to 500^2.  That is, up to $1/(249998\times249999)$.  And the remaining terms are positive, so the complete sum is more than this.

Comment: Here is a way to write this sum, each term of the original is a + - pair in this.
$$
\frac{1}{2}\;\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{(k + \mathrm{ceil} (\sqrt{k}))} - (-1)^{(k + \mathrm{floor} (\sqrt{k}))}}{k}
$$