Systematic way to compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(n) / Q(n)$ for polynomials $P$ and $Q$
This may be well known so feel free to downvote.
When $P = 1$ and $Q(x) = x^k$, this is of course the Riemann zeta function. But what about other cases?
For instance is it always possible to express $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1 / (n^k - 1)$ in terms of $\pi$ and $\zeta$ at odd integers?
Or perhaps there is a "minimal" set of algebraically independent constants that can express all such infinite sums (provided they converge, or even if not, in the smoothed sense); according to this MO answer, $\zeta(2k + 1)$ are expected to be algebraically independent.
More ambitiously, are there nontrivial cases of transcendental functions $F$ (other than exponential e.g.) for which $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1 / F(n)$ can be evaluated in closed form?

Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory" or "cv.complex-variables". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/

See my old answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/26133/297 .

For $P$ and $Q$ polynomials with rational coefficients, these sums should be periods. So it should be possible to extract information from Grothendieck's period conjecture on when they should be expected to be transcendental, and which ones can be expressed in terms of which ones.

For the sum to converge, we must have $P(n)/Q(n)=O(1/n^2)$ for large $n$. We first proceed by partial fraction decomposition:
$$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\sum_i\frac{a_i}{x-r_i}+\sum_j\frac{b_j}{(x-s_j)^{e_j}}$$
where the $e_j\ge2$, and $P(n)/Q(n)=O(1/n^2)$ forces $\sum_i a_i=0$.
Now we can rewrite the sum as
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{P(n)}{Q(n)}=\sum_i a_i\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n-r_i}-\frac{1}{n}\right)+\sum_j b_j\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n-s_j)^{e_j}},$$
where the first innermost sum can be done by the identity (take the logarithmic derivative of the product expansion of $\Gamma$)
$$\frac{\Gamma'(s)}{\Gamma(s)}=-\gamma-\frac1s+\sum_{n\ge1}\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+s}\right),$$
and the second innermost sum is the Hurwitz $\zeta$ value $\zeta(e_j,-s_j)$ by definition. So, every sum in question is a $\mathbb{\bar{Q}}$-linear combination of $1$, $\gamma+\Gamma'(\alpha)/\Gamma(\alpha)$ and $\zeta(k,\beta)$ for $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{\bar{Q}}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z},k\ge2$.
It remains to find $\mathbb{\bar{Q}}$-linear (or hopefully, algebraic) relations among these values. Establishing independence seems to be a hard problem in transcendence number theory (say, linear independence of $\zeta(3)$ and $1$) so let's focus on the known relations. As far as I know there are a few types of relations:

$\gamma+\Gamma'(1)/\Gamma(1)=0$.
Relations from functional equations of $\Gamma$:
$$\Gamma(s+1)=s\Gamma(s)\implies\frac{\Gamma'(s+1)}{\Gamma(s+1)}=\frac1s+\frac{\Gamma'(s)}{\Gamma(s)},$$
$$\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}\implies\frac{\Gamma'(s)}{\Gamma(s)}-\frac{\Gamma'(1-s)}{\Gamma(1-s)}=-\pi\cot(\pi z),$$
$$\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\Gamma\left(\frac{s+j}{n}\right)=(2\pi)^{\frac12(n-1)}n^{\frac12-s}\Gamma(s)\implies\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}\left(\frac{s+j}{n}\right)=n\left(-\ln n+\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}(s)\right).$$
$\zeta(k,\alpha)=1/(1+\alpha)^k+\zeta(k,\alpha+1)$.
Those coming from Fourier expansions of Bernoulli functions:
$$B_r(x)=-2\cdot r!\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(2n\pi x-r\pi/2)}{(2n\pi)^r}.$$
Taking rational values of $x$, the numerator of the summand is periodic in $n$, and can therefore be written in Hurwitz $\zeta$ values. In particular these include the values of $\zeta(2r)$.


Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but where does the $-\frac{1}{n}$ come from in the second displayed equation?

@MichaelAlbanese the sum of $a_i$ is zero, so adding those $1/n$ is adding zero, but makes the infinite sums converge. The usage of the variable $x$ is traditional in partial fractions decomposition, indicating the equality is true for all, say, reals, and not just integers.

The question is somewhat broad, which makes it hard to answer it. At any rate, the following consequence of the residue theorem is standard and relevant. See also the "Added" section.
Theorem. Let $f$ be a rational function of degree at most $-2$, with set of poles $P$. Then
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus P}f(n)=-\sum_{p\in P}\mathrm{res}_{z=p}\bigl(f(z)\pi\cot(\pi z)\bigr).$$
Examples. Using the above Theorem, we obtain the following identities.
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(6n-1)(6n-5)}=-\sum_{p\in\{1/6,5/6\}}\mathrm{res}_{z=p}\left(\frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{(6z-1)(6z-5)}\right)
=\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{3}},$$
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{n^2+1}=-\sum_{p\in\{i,-i\}}\mathrm{res}_{z=p}\left(\frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{z^2+1}\right)=\pi\coth\pi,$$
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}}\frac{1}{n^2}=-\mathrm{res}_{z=0}\left(\frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{z^2}\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{3}.$$
Using the symmetry of the summands, we can rewrite these as
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(6n-1)(6n-5)}=\frac{\pi}{8\sqrt{3}},\qquad
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2+1}=\frac{\pi\coth\pi-1}{2},\qquad
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$
Added. Inspired by David E Speyer's old answer, here is an analogous formula involving the digamma function for the sum over nonnegative integers:
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus P}f(n)=-\sum_{p\in P}\mathrm{res}_{z=p}\bigl(f(z)\psi(-z)\bigr).$$

The OP asked for sums as $n$ goes from $1$ to $\infty$, not $- \infty$ to $\infty$. That makes life significantly harder.

@DavidESpeyer Yes, I understand that. I just wanted to point out that sometimes summation from $1$ to $\infty$ that can be reduced to summation from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, as in the three examples given. At any rate, the question is very broad, so it is not clear what kind of answer the OP expects.

@DavidESpeyer See my "Added" section.

Thanks for the illustrative answer. I have never seen the theorem and had to look it up here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Summation_Formula_(Complex_Analysis). The square contour integral evaluates to 0 due to bounded was of cot away from the poles and quadratic decay of the rational function.

@JohnJiang I did not know it was on ProofWiki. I used to teach this material, so I simply copied and pasted from my lecture notes. The "Added" part was new to me, it occurred to me after seeing David E Speyer's ideas. Note that $\psi=\Gamma'/\Gamma$.

I couldn’t find the summation formula in Stein and Rami’s text. I wish there is a more comprehensive complex analysis book I can refer to. But it should be an easy exercise if I know the material better. The added part is very nice and qualifies as a full answer

Also want to add that since digamma has asymptotic growth of log z, away from the negative real axis and periodic zeros on it, it is absorbed in the 1/z^2 decay of the rational summand in appropriate square contour.

@JohnJiang Thanks for your kind words, and also the good question.
